# remove user credentials from safari browser through capabilities

Tags: ios, safari, webdriver, appium, mobile-safari

I have a use-case which involves logging in everytime, however - once a user is logged in, the next time the test runs on the same device - the user is still logged in on safari. What capability should I use to make sure the session is always clean.

I have used the following till now:

- `webdriver.session.deleteAllCookies()` - this even deletes the authentication cookie
- `"appium:cleanSession": true` - this doesn't do anything
- `"appium:fullReset": true` - this also doesn't do anything

What other options should I try ? This is specifically for safari + ios use-case